# Bridge/Bond interface not showing in ip a show

Tags: linux, redhat, linux-networking

I have created some notwork script under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` in order to set up my networking when my system comes up (RHEL8.3). In this set up i have my physical interfaces and I also have my bridge and bond interfaces.
My second bridge interface for example

```
[root@svr_1 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-bond1
DEVICE=bond1
ONBOOT=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=1 miimon=100 updelay=60000 primary=ens4f0"
BRIDGE=breth0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
MTU=9000
ONPARRENT=yes[root@svr_1 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-breth1
DEVICE=breth1
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
MTU=9000
IPADDR=xx.xx.xx.xx
NETMASK=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

When the system come up only the physical interfaces are shown with ip a show. I change some value on a physical interface configuration restart NetworkManager and I see the change applied , but this bond/bridge interfaces not showing up. Any idea what I showld chek?

```
[root@svr_1 net]# ls -la /sys/devices/virtual/net/
total 0

drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 0 Jun  9 11:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 0 Jun  9 10:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 0 Jun  9 10:21 lo
```

I used the same away for RHEL7.6 and it was working ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NM_CONTROLLED=no` to `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` fixed the issue. The `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` allow the network manager to manage the interface